# How to calculate Run-Time efficiency of this program?

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, runtime, big-o

I'm a little new to Big-O analysis so I need some help!

How do you calculate big-O run-time efficiency of this program if the algorithm "doIT" has efficiency factor of 5n?:

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    doIT(...)
```

I feel like big-O run-time would be O(n^2) in this case, since the loop itself is O(n). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. If `doIT()` is dependent on `n` itself then calling it within a loop also dependent on `n` makes the whole thing `O(n2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may do this:

[image]